# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to implement push notification for my app. i had set up the project in eclipse added google-play-services.jar in the java buildpath and checked it in order and export.so my app was working absolutely fine when i was doing registration with gcm and was getting the registration id from gcm too.but when i try to build my app from command line i am getting the below error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging

i added the google-play-services.jar in the classpath so the code compiled without any issue but at runtime i am getting the above exception.looks like its not able to find the jar at runtime. how can i make the jar available at runtime also please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to configure build path -> order and export and select(check box) the packages(jars).

Answer (score 0):

No matter what the build path contains in eclipse, it has nothing to do with an application. All the jars have to be added to the classpath. 
I would use the following command to start the application after build:

```
java -cp google.jar;jarA.jar;jarB.jar;jarC.jar -jar application.jar
```

After the -cp option fill in the semicolon separated list of jars that you use.